# atributo byte[] entity contiene cadena Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Buenas amigos,

Soy nuevo en Entity y Linq y tengo un problema qu no consigo solventar.
En una consulta tengo que comprobar si un atributo byte[] contiene un string que me pasan.

He probado de mil maneras y no me funciona, y por ultimo usando un metodo propio pero al aprecer cuando incluyo la llamada al metodo en la consulta Linq, este me tira excepción diciendome que no puedo incluir nada en Linq que no pueda ser convertido a SQL.

Esto es lo que intentaba, una vez hago el select con sus condiciones, pregunto si el parametro Content que es el string a buscar tiene algo, si es asi, llamo al metohodo CheckPatternIn array pasandole el x.Document que es el byte[] donde hay que buscar y el texto a buscar Content, convertido a byte[] como ContentBytes, y salta la excepción que comento.

Tambien he tratado a pasar el documento a string y compararlo con el string que me pasan por parametro pero Linq vuelve a darme excepción por la misma razon, aunque no sea un metodo propio, tampoco lo permite.

```
using (GPC container = new GPC()) {
var p = from t in ... 
    select t;
    if (Content != null) {
        byte[] ContentBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Content);
        p = p.Where(x => this.CheckPatternInArray(x.Document, ContentBytes) == true);
    }
 var res = p.Select(t=> new Views.xxx()
            {
                IDTx = t.Ix,
                ....
            });

            res.OrderBy(o => o.Ix);
            return res.Distinct().ToList();

private bool CheckPatternInArray(byte[] array, byte[] pattern) {
int fidx = 0;
int result = Array.FindIndex(array, 0, array.Length, (byte b) => {
    fidx = (b == pattern[fidx]) ? fidx + 1 : 0;
    return (fidx == pattern.Length);
});
return (result >= pattern.Length - 1);
```

}

Comment: Te lanza algun error la consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
var p = from t in ... 
    select t;
```

... `p` es un `IQueryable<T>`, lo que significa que, aun después de haberle asignado el valor a `p`, todavía está en modo de armar la consulta SQL.  O sea que cualquier `.Where` o `.Select` que agregues después, va a tratar de convertir la expresión en SQL.

Pero siendo que las condiciones que intentas agregar después no son traducibles a SQL, ni creo que es tu intención que haga esto, la solución es de indicar en código dónde parar la traducción a SQL.  Eso se puede lograr llamando `AsEnumerable()` para que `p` no sea más un `IQueryable<T>`, sino un `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
var p = (from t in ... 
    select t).AsEnumerable();
```

Al hacer esto, todas las condiciones que le agregues después se aplicarán en memoria sobre los datos que te devuelva la consulta a la base de datos, en vez de tratar de incorporar estas condiciones al SQL directamente.

Comment: Gracias @sstan, el problema es que justo si despues del select lo convierto  a IEnumerable<T> con AsEnumerable()  para hacer uso de mi metodo que comprueba si se contiene el string, tengo un problema y es que para devolver los datos hago uso justo despues de comprobar eso de : var res = p.Select(t=> new Views.vistaPropia()
                {
                    IDx = t.IDX
                    ...
                });  res.OrderBy(o => o.Ix);
            return res.Distinct().ToList(); Por tanto al no ser p un IQueryable no funcionara. Que solucion le ves?

Comment: ¿Lo probastes? Todo ese código que hace `.Select`, `.OrderBy`, `Distinct().toList()`, etc... debería funcionar perfectamente con un `IEnuemrable<T>`. Al no ser un `IQueryable<T>`, lo único que cambia es que las operaciones no forman parte de la consulta SQL, sino que se aplican en memoria después que el SQL ya se ejecutó, que francamente, creo que es tu única opción según lo que veo.

Comment: No puedo probarlo hasta mañana por la mañana en el trabajo. Pero si dices que el var res = p.Select(t=> new ViewsVistaPropia(){... funcionará , sería una genial solución. Mañana te confirmo. Gracias.

Comment: acabo de probarlo, y tan pronto hago IEnumerable la consulta como tengo por despues   p= p.Where(p => (p.Tabla.... no me devuelve nada...

Comment: finalmente jugando con unas variable y el IEnumerable funciona, mil millones de gracias compi